Spatial Join that pulls in only the first intersect?
I’d like use the spatial join tool to join attributes from the red centerline (road) with the blue polygon. I’m using ‘join one to one’ and intersect but the problem is it will join the 211 road and not the 551 which is the first one it intersects with and the only one I actually want for the spatial join. Anyone know how to use this tool so that it will only join with the first line it intersects?

How should it decide which is "first" in such a way that would apply to all polygons and lines?

@SonofaBeach hmm I suppose you’re right. My thinking was that because the blue polygon is a buffer out to the left then it should intersect with the first street it crosses. Any idea how to achieve this?
